# Buttons in ubuntu touch toolbar

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

What is the code to have a toolbar with buttons when programing in QML with the Ubuntu Components Module. I want to make it so that when I swipe a finger from the bottom of the screen the toolbar comes up with buttons on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by adding a `ToolbarItems` component to your Page's `tools` property: http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-1.0/Ubuntu.Components.ToolbarItems/

The `MainView` will look for that property, and if it has actions it will automatically add the necessary toolbar and make it respond to swiping-up from the bottom.